# Getting the result with date from yesterday

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to tally all Invoices without Sales Order and show it as an SQL query. The date should be the Invoices entered yesterday. The challenge is it seems that the result is static and won't change

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(dd, - 1, GETDATE()), 103) AS Date,
                         'Invoices w/o SO' AS Type,
                         COUNT(dbo.Invoice.InvoiceID) AS Orders,
                         COUNT(dbo.Invoice.InvoiceID) AS Chairs, 
                         ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(dbo.InvoiceDetails.ExtendedPrice), 2), 0) AS [Total Ex GST] 
FROM dbo.Invoice INNER JOIN dbo.Customers 
     ON dbo.Invoice.CustomerID = dbo.Customers.CustomerID 
     INNER JOIN dbo.InvoiceDetails 
     ON dbo.Invoice.InvoiceID = dbo.InvoiceDetails.InvoiceID
WHERE (dbo.InvoiceDetails.ItemNo = 'TRIAL CHAIR') 
      OR
      (dbo.InvoiceDetails.ItemNo = 'STORAGE') 
      OR
      (dbo.InvoiceDetails.ItemNo = 'RSTF01') 
      OR
      (dbo.InvoiceDetails.ItemNo = 'FRDMC01') 
      AND 
      (dbo.Invoice.CredInvoiceNo IS NULL) 
      AND 
      (dbo.Invoice.EntryDate >= CONVERT(char(8), DATEADD(dd, - 1, GETDATE()), 112)) 
      AND 
      (dbo.Customers.CustomerID <> 187)
```

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: You are doing a string compare, not a date compare which is not going to work as you expect. Hopefully you are storing your `EntryDate` as a date, in which case just remove the `convert(char(8), ...)`, if you are not then convert your `EntryDate` to a date, and again remove the `convert(char(8), ...)`.

Comment: Why not use an `IN` instead of all those `OR`s? The ISO date format on strong would format for `>` and `<` operators however, it is ill-advised. Store and treat dates as what they are, a `date`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.
I changed the query and it worked!

```
SELECT
  CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE()), 103) AS Date,
  'Invoices w/o SO' AS Type,
  COUNT(dbo.Invoice.InvoiceID) AS Orders,
  COUNT(dbo.Invoice.InvoiceID) AS Chairs,
  ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(dbo.InvoiceDetails.ExtendedPrice), 2), 0) AS [Total Ex GST]
FROM dbo.Invoice
INNER JOIN dbo.Customers
  ON dbo.Invoice.CustomerID = dbo.Customers.CustomerID
INNER JOIN dbo.InvoiceDetails
  ON dbo.Invoice.InvoiceID = dbo.InvoiceDetails.InvoiceID
WHERE (dbo.InvoiceDetails.ItemNo IN ('TRIAL CHAIR', 'STORAGE', 'RSTF01', 'FRDMC01'))
AND (dbo.Invoice.CredInvoiceNo IS NULL)
AND (dbo.Customers.CustomerID <> 187)
AND (DATEDIFF(DAY, dbo.Invoice.EntryDate, GETDATE()) = 1)
```

Comment: This query might "work" as in it doesn't return an error, but it can't possibly return meaningful results. For examples, `Orders` and `Chairs` will always be the same number (and if that's expected, you don't need both columns in the output). A couple of other things, [don't use `varchar` without length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length), and flip the last `datediff` around, you shouldn't be converting every value in the table to compare it to a constant.